# How to print additional row based on the current column value using AWK

Tags: awk

I have a txt file containing:

```
adf8261:21:09:07 BAT SYNTAX_fa TRUE 273e-9,218e-9,136e-9,82e-9,82e-9,27e-9,0
qwe8261:21:09:10 BAT SYNTAX_fa TRUE 54e-9,27e-9,0
oiu8261:21:09:08 BAT SYNTAX_fa TRUE 27e-9,27e-9,27e-9,0
```

and based on the column 5, I wanted to put all the value in one column using AWK. "," is used to separate the data.

Result will be like this:

```
adf8261:21:09:07 BAT SYNTAX_fa TRUE 273e-9
adf8261:21:09:07 BAT SYNTAX_fa TRUE 218e-9
adf8261:21:09:07 BAT SYNTAX_fa TRUE 136e-9
adf8261:21:09:07 BAT SYNTAX_fa TRUE 82e-9
adf8261:21:09:07 BAT SYNTAX_fa TRUE 82e-9
adf8261:21:09:07 BAT SYNTAX_fa TRUE 27e-9
adf8261:21:09:07 BAT SYNTAX_fa TRUE 0
qwe8261:21:09:10 BAT SYNTAX_fa TRUE 54e-9
qwe8261:21:09:10 BAT SYNTAX_fa TRUE 27e-9
qwe8261:21:09:10 BAT SYNTAX_fa TRUE 0
oiu8261:21:09:08 BAT SYNTAX_fa TRUE 27e-9
oiu8261:21:09:08 BAT SYNTAX_fa TRUE 27e-9
oiu8261:21:09:08 BAT SYNTAX_fa TRUE 27e-9
oiu8261:21:09:08 BAT SYNTAX_fa TRUE 0
```

Comment: What did you try for yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***awk*** solution:

```
awk -F'[[:space:]]+|,' '{ for(i=5;i<=NF;i++) print $1,$2,$3,$4,$i }' file
```

- `-F'[[:space:]]+|,'` - whitespace and comma are treated as field separator
- `for(i=5;i<=NF;i++)` - iterating though the *items* of the 5th field

The output:

```
adf8261:21:09:07 BAT SYNTAX_fa TRUE 273e-9
adf8261:21:09:07 BAT SYNTAX_fa TRUE 218e-9
adf8261:21:09:07 BAT SYNTAX_fa TRUE 136e-9
adf8261:21:09:07 BAT SYNTAX_fa TRUE 82e-9
adf8261:21:09:07 BAT SYNTAX_fa TRUE 82e-9
adf8261:21:09:07 BAT SYNTAX_fa TRUE 27e-9
adf8261:21:09:07 BAT SYNTAX_fa TRUE 0
qwe8261:21:09:10 BAT SYNTAX_fa TRUE 54e-9
qwe8261:21:09:10 BAT SYNTAX_fa TRUE 27e-9
qwe8261:21:09:10 BAT SYNTAX_fa TRUE 0
oiu8261:21:09:08 BAT SYNTAX_fa TRUE 27e-9
oiu8261:21:09:08 BAT SYNTAX_fa TRUE 27e-9
oiu8261:21:09:08 BAT SYNTAX_fa TRUE 27e-9
oiu8261:21:09:08 BAT SYNTAX_fa TRUE 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Another in awk using `split`:

```
$ awk '{split($5,a,",");for(i in a) print $1,$2,$3,$4,a[i]}' file
adf8261:21:09:07 BAT SYNTAX_fa TRUE 82e-9
adf8261:21:09:07 BAT SYNTAX_fa TRUE 82e-9
adf8261:21:09:07 BAT SYNTAX_fa TRUE 27e-9
adf8261:21:09:07 BAT SYNTAX_fa TRUE 0
adf8261:21:09:07 BAT SYNTAX_fa TRUE 273e-9
adf8261:21:09:07 BAT SYNTAX_fa TRUE 218e-9
adf8261:21:09:07 BAT SYNTAX_fa TRUE 136e-9
qwe8261:21:09:10 BAT SYNTAX_fa TRUE 54e-9
qwe8261:21:09:10 BAT SYNTAX_fa TRUE 27e-9
qwe8261:21:09:10 BAT SYNTAX_fa TRUE 0
oiu8261:21:09:08 BAT SYNTAX_fa TRUE 0
oiu8261:21:09:08 BAT SYNTAX_fa TRUE 27e-9
oiu8261:21:09:08 BAT SYNTAX_fa TRUE 27e-9
oiu8261:21:09:08 BAT SYNTAX_fa TRUE 27e-9
```

Output will be in random order due to `for(i in a)`. That can be fixed with:

```
... n=split($5,a,","); for(i=1;i<=n;i++) print ...
```

Comment: also can be fixed with `split($5,a,","); for(i=1;i in a;i++)`